# How to subscribe Observable after another one

Tags: angular, observable

I want to get current login user after login but this.router.navigate([this.returnUrl]); not run : what i wrong here and what i can fix this

```
onSubmit(): void {
    this.authService.login(this.loginForm.value).subscribe(next => {
    }, error => {
      this.alertService.error(error.error);
    }, () => {
      this.authService.getCurrentUser().subscribe(u => localStorage.setItem('role', u.role), error => {
        this.alertService.error(error.error);
      }, () => {
        this.router.navigate([this.returnUrl]);
      });
    });
  }
```

Comment: You can make your method asynchronous

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A good practice is to use [mergeMap](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/transformation/mergemap) to chain API calls like this:

```
onSubmit(): void {
    this.authService.login(this.loginForm.value).pipe(
        mergeMap(() => this.authService.getCurrentUser()),
        catchError(err => this.alertService.error(err.error)),
        finalize(() => this.router.navigate([this.returnUrl]))
    ).subscribe(u => {
        localStorage.setItem('role', u.role);
    });
}
```

Also note that I added a [catchError](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/error_handling/catch) directly in the pipe, but you can also catch the error in the subscribe as follow:

```
onSubmit(): void {
    this.authService.login(this.loginForm.value).pipe(
        mergeMap(() => this.authService.getCurrentUser())
    ).subscribe(
        u => localStorage.setItem('role', u.role),
        err => this.alertService.error(err.error),
        () => this.router.navigate([this.returnUrl])
    );
}
```

Another important thing in your code is that you placed your navigate in a finally block which means that you will redirect in both case of success **or** error. This is why I placed a [finalize](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/utility/finalize) in the first example. If the routing is meant to be **only** on success, the code should be:

```
onSubmit(): void {
    this.authService.login(this.loginForm.value).pipe(
        mergeMap(() => this.authService.getCurrentUser()),
        catchError(err => this.alertService.error(err.error))
    ).subscribe(u => {
        localStorage.setItem('role', u.role);
        this.router.navigate([this.returnUrl]);
    });
}
```

or

```
onSubmit(): void {
    this.authService.login(this.loginForm.value).pipe(
        mergeMap(() => this.authService.getCurrentUser())
    ).subscribe(
        u => {
            localStorage.setItem('role', u.role);
            this.router.navigate([this.returnUrl]);
        },
        err => this.alertService.error(err.error)
    );
}
```